# How can I locate my missing azure virtual machines

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

I have created 4 Azure VM a while back. I can still log in to them and I know they are live. But I can find in all the subscriptions account I have, ;-(. Can you help me out how I can locate them back?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: [Obligatory bash.org link](http://bash.org/?5273)